# Input should remain there when page is refreshed

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to implement a feature in my search engine. When I search for something that 'keyword' remains there and shows results. But when I refresh the page, that 'keyword' disappears from the search bar but results remains the same.

I tried to google this issue and found some results on stackoverflow. I used `autocomplete="off"` but still issue has not been solved.

```
<div class="input-text">
      <input #input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" id="nav-input" (keyup)="onquery($event)" autocomplete="off"
           [(ngModel)]="searchdata.query">
</div>
```

It will be great, if someone can help me out! Thanks :)

Comment: when you refresh the page you re-load the entire app from scratch so any information you had stored in memory will disappear...

Comment: use can use localStorage to persist data between realoads

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova Thanks for giving time to my question. Okay, I'll try using `localStorage`

Comment: You can also use cookies!